# How graph function $z^2 = xy$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

If we want to graph $z^2=xy$ we get this picture.

[image]

My question is without using any application how can I deduce that graph of above function will be this? For one-variable we are calculating for example derivatives finding extremas and then we plot using that information.For example it's clear that we only should look where $x>0,y>0$ and $x<0,y<0.$ But how understand that it will be conic shape?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The method I learned long ago was: rotate to eliminate mixed products.  In this case, rotate about the $z$-axis by 45 degrees to eliminate the $xy$ term.  That is, use the substitution
$$
x = \frac{X+Y}{\sqrt{2}},\qquad y = \frac{X-Y}{\sqrt2}
$$
With that substitution, the equation $z^2 = xy$ becomes
$$
z^2 = \frac{X^2}{2}-\frac{Y^2}{2} ,
$$
which (hopefully) you can recognize as a cone.
Rearranging,
$$
Y^2 = X^2+2z^2
$$
I can tell this is a cone, whose axis is the $Y$-axis [in the original
coordinates, the line $x+y=0,z=0$], and whose cross-sections perpendicular to the axis are ellipses.

---

Colleges and universities in the US used to have a course "Analytic Geometry" which students would take before Calculus (or concurrently).  Some time around the 1960s, there was an "improvement" to the math curriculum.  A new, combined, course called "Calculus and Analytic Geometry" replaced the two old courses.  Unfortunately, some of the topics of the old Analytic Geometry course had to be deleted.

---

Why is that substitution a 45 degree rotation?

The rotation in the $xy$ plane with angle $\alpha$ is
$$
x = (\cos \alpha) X + (\sin \alpha) Y\\
y = (-\sin\alpha) X + (\cos\alpha)  Y
$$
In this problem, in $xy$ I substitute that in, collect coefficients of $X^2, XY, Y^2$.  Then equate the coefficient of $XY$ to zero to find what angle rotation eliminates that term.  That's the general method.  But
I use rotation $45$ degrees so often that I just recognize what to do.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Sorry if this is silly question but why that substitution corresponds to $45$ degree rotation?

Comment: Do you have any source for the mentioned "improvement" around 1960s?

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an *equation* in the three knowns $x,y$, and $z$, not a "function".

The general topic is called "[quadratic surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric#Euclidean_space)", which is closely related to [quadratic forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form). For surfaces that are defined by quadratic equations, what you do is
first write it in one of the [normal forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric#Euclidean_space) by changing coordinates. The classifications are well known.

The general process of getting the normal forms is called [orthogonal diagonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_diagonalization).
GEdgar's calculation shows you that you have an example of [elliptic cones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric#Euclidean_space).